# gvim chdir on startup when a folder is dropped

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I can open a gvim session and drag&drop a folder while holding the `shift` key to change `pwd` to the dropped folder. This works fine but I was wondering if it's possible to do the same without first opening a gvim (I can drop a folder on a gvim icon on my desktop to start a gvim session with the given folder but it does not change the working directory even when I hold shift key).

If relevant, I'm using an `ubuntu` system with `unity` desktop and also `NERDTree plugin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
au VimEnter * if isdirectory(expand('%')) | cd % | endif
```

Comment: Try to drag file to vim-icon to open it. Type `:pwd` in vim to check current dir.

Comment: ah I see, it works for files but that's not what I need. I need to make it work for folders. I could as well use `autochdir` for files.